# How to exclude weekends and holidays in a query

Tags: sql-server

I have been tasked with creating a flat file. One of the fields that I need is a date field. I need the disco date to be LAST_EVENT_PROC_DT + 12 unless that date falls on a weekend or holiday,if so the disco date would be the next business day. This date field is stored in my system as a Numeric field. I am trying to write it is a case statement using our holiday table and some weekend exclusion code.
This is the column I am trying to query:

```
LAST_EVENT_PROC_DT (numeric(8,0),not null)
```

It holds a date formatted like: 20150506

This is the flat file output:

```
'' + '|' +
'' + '|' +
cast(q.NEXT_EVENT_PROC_DT as varchar) + '|' + -- Due Date
cast(q.LAST_EVENT_PROC_DT +12 as varchar) + '|' + -- Disco Date = Due date +15
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE() +15,112) + '|' + -- Agency Send Date todays date + 15
```

I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Federal holidays? Religious holidays? Country specific holidays? Bank holidays? When it comes to holidays it's usually best to develop your own set of dates (read: calendar) you can compare against and modify as needed. If you can convert that date format into an actual `DATE` column, you'll make life easier since  you can get the day of the week with `select datename(dw,getdate())`

Comment: Firstly, never store your dates as numeric. There is a `DATE` type in SQL Server for a reason.  I would have a dates table that holds the Next Business Day `CREATE TABLE dbo.dates(date DATE, next_business_day DATE);`. It really simplifies things when you need to work out things like this.

Comment: This is for bank holidays. I know they should be formatted as Date but I cant change it. I am also unable to create a Dates table. I do have a holidays table.

Comment: Why are you using `VARCHAR` without **length** ? check [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you cannot create a permanent table and you have serious issues with your database design...your best best would be to create a temp table, populate it, then query using an `APPLY` to get the next available date that is neither a holiday, nor weekend.

The basic design of this table was lifted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17431929/775200), I've just added weekends.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #Dates (
  d DATE,
  isWeekend BIT,
  PRIMARY KEY (d)
)
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '2000-01-01'
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = '2100-01-01'


WHILE ( @dIncr < @dEnd )
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO #Dates (d, isWeekend) VALUES( @dIncr,  IIF(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @dIncr) IN (7, 1), 1, 0 ))
  SELECT @dIncr = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dIncr )
END
```

Once you've got the in a temp table and identified those that are weekends, construct your main query...

I apologise for the roughness of this, there's not a lot of your table available above.

```
SELECT
  '' + '|' +
  '' + '|' +
  cast(q.NEXT_EVENT_PROC_DT as varchar) + '|' + -- Due Date
  cast(dates.d as varchar) + '|' + -- Disco Date = Due date +15
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE() +15,112) + '|' + -- Agency Send Date todays date + 15
  ...
FROM <TABLE>
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 d
  FROM #Dates AS dates
  LEFT OUTER JOIN <holidays> ON holidays.date = dates.d
  WHERE d >= DATEADD(DAY, 12, CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8), q.LAST_EVENT_PROC_DT) AS DATE))
    AND d.IsWeekend = 0
    AND holidays.date IS NULL
  ORDER BY d ASC
) AS dates
```

Answer (score 3):

You Can simply use datediff function of sql. and then you can subtract weekends between those dates if any.Here Sunday is set as a firstday of week, For example check below query.

```
Declare @startdatee as DateTime
Declare @enddatee as DateTime
Set @startdatee = GETDATE();
set @enddatee = GETDATE()+1;
select @startdatee,@enddatee,(datediff(day,@startdatee,@enddatee+1)-(2)*datediff(week,@startdatee,@enddatee))
```

And If You want to exclude holiday's too, then, You also can calculate holidays between start/end date and can subtract that from final selection.
i gave you example here.
You can use your holiday's table,here i am just using temp table for example.

```
Declare @holidays Table (ID int,Name Varchar(50),[Date] date)
Insert into @holidays VALUES 
(1,'holiday1','2018-07-07'),
(2,'holiday2','2018-07-12')

Declare 
    @startdate datetime = '2018-07-02',
    @enddate datetime =  '2018-07-30',
    @holiday int = 0

    Set @holiday = (Select COUNT(*) FROM @holidays WHERE (Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) 
                    AND DATEPART(Weekday,Date) not in (1,7)
                    )

SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(case datepart(dw, @StartDate) when 1 then 1 else 0 end) 
  -(case datepart(dw, @EndDate) when 7 then 1 else 0 end)
  -@holiday
```

Comment: Needed to add checks for starting on Saturday / ending on Sunday and the `+1` on the DATEDIFF(dd will depend on requirements (whether start/end is inclusive).  But otherwise substantially outperformed the code had previously.